# Resharper Suggestion Color Issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

I have a strange bug in resharper 4.5 in VS 2005.  Instead of doing the usual underline for a suggestion -- IE: telling me that a using statement is unnecessary, it is setting the background to red in the same manner as a breakpoint.  Here is a [screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/2q0n69v/6).

I have uninstalled and reinstalled several times, including an install of resharper 5.0 to no avail.  I also went into the fonts/color section in the options and have set the Resharper options to standard squiggly underlines.  I have also tried resetting the colors to default, and I also tried deleting my .resharper files and .suo files out of desperation.

Has anyone run into this issue?  Are there any suggestions that I could try to reset resharper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem which is actually caused by a bug in Visual Studio 2005. This bug is fixed in SP1, so please make sure you have SP1 for VS2005 installed.

Comment: I'll try this, just need to download it first.  I'll post back after install.

Comment: This worked indeed.  Thanks a ton!  This had been bothering me for months.

Answer (score 2):

What settings do you have in ReSharper | Options | Inspection Severity for "Redundant using directive"? Mine is set to "Show as warning" - however, this is mostly for the behaviour of the shortcut bar.

The using statement is coloured as per the "ReSharper Dead Code" value in Tools | Options | Fonts and Colors - what's this set to? Mine has Item foreground" set to a grey, and "Item background" set to "Default".

The .resharper files are for project specific settings, and the .suo file are nothing to do with this either. The ReSharper configuration is stored in an XML file in your local profile (AppData/Application Data/etc depending on OS).

---

**Edit to respond to comment**

Hmm. I'd say you have something wrong with your install then - ReSharper 4.5.x on VS2008 has some 40 items on the Text Editor section of Fonts and Colours, up from just over 30 in 2.0 on VS 2003 - both of which have "ReSharper Dead Code" as an option.

Comment: I dont have a 'Resharper Dead Code' option in that menu.  I have 'Resharper Field Identifier', 'Resharper Implements and Hides' and 'Resharper Suggestion'.  You are looking in the Text Editor section of the Fonts and Colors section, right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the community forum for resharper? http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/community/resharper

Maybe this is a known bug/fix/tweak?

Comment: Yes, I have looked.  I was planning on posting there if I couldn't get an answer here.

Comment: I don't think this answer helps at all